# Find largest negative integer

Tags: number-theory

> Hi, I need to find the largest negative integer satisfying

$$47\mid 12x-13\quad \text{and} \quad 153\mid x-3$$

Not getting any ideas to start

Comment: First, find all the integers satisfying those two relations. Then, pick out the largest negative one. So, do you know how to find integers satisfying the two relations?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$12x\equiv13\pmod{47}\implies4\cdot12x\equiv4\cdot13\pmod{47}$$

$$\iff x\equiv52\equiv5\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$x\equiv3\pmod{153}\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Now use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve the system of modular equations
$$\begin{cases}12x-13\equiv 0\pmod{47}\\x-3\equiv 0\pmod{153}\end{cases}$$
or equivalently
$$\begin{cases}12x\equiv 13\pmod{47}\\x\equiv 3\pmod{153}\end{cases}$$
Notice that $47$ and $153$ are relatively prime, so the Chinese remainder theorem can be used for the general solution.